# How to convert matrices to column vectors and append all together in python

Tags: python, vector, matrix, append

I'm more familiar with Matlab, but I'm current working with python. If I have 4 matrices / arrays in python, how can I covert each to a column vector and then append them together to form one large column vector?

In Matlab, I have:

```
W1 = rand(hiddenSize, visibleSize) * 2 * r - r;
W2 = rand(visibleSize, hiddenSize) * 2 * r - r;
b1 = zeros(hiddenSize, 1);
b2 = zeros(visibleSize, 1);

theta = [W1(:) ; W2(:) ; b1(:) ; b2(:)];
```

theta is the final column vector I'm interested in. How would I do this in python?

I think that I would use reshape function to create the column vectors (something like     W1 = reshape(W1, size(W1)) ), but I couldn't get that to work and I'm not sure how to append each to create one large column vector. Any insight would be great!

Comment: Maybe I'm just being slow, but by taking a matrix and making it a column vector, are you wanting to flatten it? also, what dimensions are they?

Comment: Yes, I guess I want to flatten it. I know next to nothing about python.. is there a simple way to flatten a matrix and then append them? W1 is 25 x 64, W2 is 64 x 25, b1 is just a vector of length 25, and b2 is a vector of length 64

Edit: I see there is a flatten() function. I'll try working with that for now. Thanks!

Comment: Are you working with numPy? if you're not, I would suggest you try it out.

Comment: Using flatten() will give me an array. In Python, is there a simple way to covert that into a column vector?

Comment: Transpose? I'm not by my computer. But numpy has all of the functions you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are moving from Matlab to Python, I highly recommend you install the [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) (and maybe [Scipy](https://scipy.org/)) packages.

Using NumPy you could do this:

```
import numpy as np
W1 = np.arange(25*64).reshape(25, 64)
W2 = np.arange(25*64).reshape(64, 25)
b1 = np.arange(25)
b2 = np.arange(64)

theta = np.concatenate([W1.flat, W2.flat, b1, b2])
print(theta.shape)
# (3289,)
```

Here is an [introduction to NumPy for Matlab users](https://web.archive.org/web/20150818181140/http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users).

Comment: Thank you very much!! I really appreciate your help and I'll definitely be studying up on NumPy. Thanks!!